# Docker not installing composer dependencies after image built

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I built a simple dockerfile using php5.6-fpm image. This file should run my site php code and install all required dependencies. The problem is that php is working, but dependencies like

composer install --working-dir=/var/www/html $COMPOSER_ARGS

and

cp /var/www/html/config.inc.php.dist /var/www/html/config.inc.php

are not installed.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
LABEL maintainer "karolis@pretendentas.lt"

WORKDIR /var/www/html

VOLUME /var/www/html
EXPOSE 9000

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN set -ex \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        zip \
        git \
        libxml2-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) bcmath gd mysqli opcache soap

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/php/session \
    && mkdir -p /var/lib/php/wsdlcache \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/session \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/wsdlcache \
    && chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENV GITHUB_TOKEN ********************

RUN set -ex \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
        --install-dir=/usr/bin \
        --filename=composer \
    && composer config -g github-oauth.github.com $GITHUB_TOKEN

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ -f var/www/html/docker/init.sh ]; then
    sleep 5 && echo "[info] Running /var/www/html/init.sh script" && sh /var/www/html/init.sh &
fi

docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm
```

**init.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /var/www/html/composer.json ] && [ ! -d /var/www/html/vendor ]; then
   echo "[info] Composer install"
   composer install --working-dir=/var/www/html $COMPOSER_ARGS
fi


if [ ! -f /var/www/html/config.inc.php ]; then
    echo "[info] Copy default config"
    cp /var/www/html/config.inc.php.dist /var/www/html/config.inc.php
fi
```

this is php image snippet from docker-compose file:

```
php:
    image: pretendentas/php5.6-test
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you ask into wrong path to execute the file.

dockerfile

```
COPY init.sh /var/www/html/init.sh
```

entrypoint.sh

```
if [ -f var/wwww/html/docker/init.sh ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix the typos here:

```
if [ -f var/wwww/html/docker/init.sh ];
```

To:

```
if [ -f /var/www/html/docker/init.sh ];
```

However, take into account that the COPY of init.sh is being overrided by the volume. So in the `entrypoint.sh` refer to the correct path of `init.sh`. I assume that `init.sh` is in the project root dir, so it is located at the root of the volume: `/var/www/html`

```
if [ -f /var/www/html/init.sh ]; then
    sleep 5 && echo "[info] Running /var/www/html/init.sh script " && sh /var/www/html/init.sh &
fi
```

Comment: ok, so i deleted COPY init.sh /var/www/html line from dockerfile and moved init.sh directly to /var/www/html folder on my host machine. But still dependencies are not being installed

Comment: Not in your host machine. The file must be in the same dir as docker-compose.yml (because you are mounting `.`->`/var/www/html/`

Comment: Sorry for the bad expression. Yes, init.sh is in the same directory as docker-compose-development.yml file

to bring all containers up I'm using this command: docker-compose -f docker-compose-development.yml up

Comment: Perfect. Is it fixed now?

Comment: The problem still remains, packages a not installed ;(

Comment: Do you see this in the output? `echo "[info] Composer install"`

Comment: These are the only 2 outputs from php conteiner:

php_1       | [13-Jun-2017 21:06:14] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 5

php_1       | [13-Jun-2017 21:06:14] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

Comment: Please run this: `docker-compose -f docker-compose-development.yml run php ls -l /var/www/html`

Comment: Creating ejuralt_db_1
[13-Jun-2017 21:31:00] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 6
[13-Jun-2017 21:31:00] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

Comment: Please check that you have all vendor/, composer.json, config.inc.php and init.sh in your project dir, next to docker-compose.yml

Comment: composer.json, config.inc.php.dist and init.sh are next to docker-compose-development.yml file. /vendor folder and config.inc.php should be generated after bash runs init.sh file

Comment: here is the image of my files:
https://gyazo.com/c8f73723dc635cc53978006b185dee9c

Comment: To see what is happening add `set -x` after `#!/bin/bash` in each script file. And show us the output when compose up again

Comment: php_1       | + '[' -f var/www/html/init.sh ']'
php_1       | + docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm
php_1       | [13-Jun-2017 22:03:58] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 5
php_1       | [13-Jun-2017 22:03:58] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

Comment: You have not fixed the typo `var/www/...` (you're missing the leading `/`. A common mistake is not build again: add --build to the compose up command

Comment: Sorry, forget about the build due to you are using volume